# Individual Item Probability From Forecasted Counts

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, python, count-data

My data is a time series, in which I need to be able to predict which day and hour an occurrence of an event is most likely to occur. To answer this question, I have constructed a SARIMA model on the aggregated count by day/hour, which is performing well.

However, although I can predict the counts, I have no idea on how to tie this back to get the individual probability of each event. Any direction on what to look into, or a different approach would be greatly appreciated. I apologize as I am new to data science.